# Autopopulate Form in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to find a way populate a form group with text given the click of a button. I am using angularJs,JQuery, jsPDF, and html for this. The data will be partially pre formatted, e.g. "Thank you for joining us, for any questions call this number", and also to contain JSON Data, e.g. "To, {{client.name}}". Here is the html for the form group:

```
`<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="flyer-description">Description</label>
 <textarea class="form-control" id="flyer-description"   placeholder="Insert a short description taking care of the available space">This is where Header, Body, and Footer of Letter Go! Please click corresponding button to fill this area.</textarea>
 </div>`
```

I would like this button, on click event, to populate this text area with desired text:

`<tr><td><a ng-href="" class="btn btn-primary">Client Welcome </a></td>`

Here is my controller for client info:

```
function ClientCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.clients = [];
$http.get('/client').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.clients = data;
    if (data == "") {
        $scope.clients = [];
    }
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Ops: could not get any data");
});
```

However, unfortunately I am a little lost as to the script to use to implement the such. I believe you would need to find id of the form, then insert a given text. I am not looking for anyone to write the script for me, but to suggest ways, directives, etc.. to use.

Comment: Where is the data that is supposed to populate the form?

Comment: The data will be partially pre formatted, e.g. "Thank you for joining us", and also to contain JSON Data, e.g. "To, {{client.name}}".

Comment: I suspect that no one is going to be able to answer your question with so little code to review.  You need to include the js controller showing where your data is coming from.  Is it an http call?  Is is static?  You need to provide much more than what you have thus far.  I will try to help you, but I can't offer any assistance given so little information.

Comment: I do apologize for the lack of information. I am getting my json data via http call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular way:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGwFe2GS5dO6Iwg8rpiE?p=preview)

I made an another example in jquery, on click of the button, get the json data, and set the value of the textarea, see the plunker to view the working code:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh3RhFgyDV4i4B97tGsT?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>Client Welcome</button>
  </body>

</html>

$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
      $('textarea').val('Thank you for joining us, for any questions call this number, to ' + data.name);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: OP attached AngularJS in the tag. If so, using jQuery to manipulate DOM is not a good practice in AngularJS.

Comment: I did another example in angular

Comment: To implement multiple buttons, can I give each button an id and put: $('buttonid').on('click', function() { ..... ?

Comment: yes, if you have the same code in your function click, it would be better you create a class to all buttons, if it's a different code you can use the id, remember, the id must be unique, please mark my answer as correct :D

Comment: I will mark as correct as soon as I can get to work. I am trying your code with one button, but unfortunately I cannot get it to work just yet.

Comment: Yes, I did -- in my console log I get a 404 error for my url for the json. I believe this obstructs the function from placing a value in text area as well. I am trying to sort out.

Comment: Will you look at my client controller, which contains the code for how I get the client json data ? Should I use $http.get instead of $.getJSON ?

Comment: You have a problem with the path to your json file, because this you get the 404 error

Comment: Or since I already get the client json in the html using angular, can I pass that into my function instead of getting the data again ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114078/discussion-between-aaron-oberlander-and-jorge-hess).

Comment: You need to use $http.get, see my angular example, your unique problem is path to your json file